# With Mongo DB is there a benefit to splitting up my collection?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection called **products**. My 6 Different user types can add  products to the system, all with same product schema. I can associate products with user type and I have no problems doing it this way, but I don't know what it will be like as the collection get larger and larger in terms of manageability.

The way the app works is that each user type can only see the products listed by specific other user type(s). For example **userType2** can only see products listed by userType1, **userType3** can see products from userType2 and userType4. Something like that.

I was thinking of giving each user type their own collection for products like this:

**userType1_products**, **userType2_products**, **userType3_products**, etc.

Will this be at all beneficial or should I just stick with a single collection for all products? Advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this decission should be made based on modelling the domain you are working on, not on performace. MongoDB is designed to scale out if you [shard your collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/) and add additional server nodes you will not have any big performance problems when holding all your products in one collection.

As the products have all the same schema, I would hold them all in the same collection if at least one operation acts over the products regardless of the user type. If you always decide on the users type on what to do with the products, this would be a modelling information where splitting the products based on the user type into multiple collections will make your data more understandable for everyone who has to work with it.

Work on performance when it is a problem. Focus on understandable data first and model your world correctly.

Comment: I decided to stick with a single collection and it's been working out great.